# MySQL merge two tables of different database to single database

Tags: mysql, merge-replication, merge

Friends, i have database named as DB1 with a table called TB1A and another database as DB2 with  a table TB2A.

TB1A having 5 columns and TB2A  having 8 columns, All the columns available in TB1A is present in TB2A.

I want to create new table called TB3A which should be a merged result of a TB1A and TB2A. Means TB3A will have 8 columns and contains all the datas of TB1A and TB2A.

```
CREATE TABLE TB3A AS (

SELECT * 
  FROM DB1.TB1A 
  JOIN  DB2.TB2A 
)
```

While i trying like above it is showing an error like below

> Error Code: 1060
>
> Duplicate column name 'Agreement_Id'
>
> Execution Time : 0 sec
>
> Transfer Time  : 0 sec
>
> Total Time     : 0 sec

Does any one have any idea about this. I have google it this issue but i am not able to find the solution for this ..

Comment: What part of the error message seems unclear? Obviously you cannot have two columns with the same name in a table.

Comment: Do you want 13 columns?  Do the tables have the same number of rows?  Is that how many rows you should have in the result?  We need some understanding of what you mean by "merge" -- to decide whether to recommend CROSS JOIN (as already mentioned in one anwser) versus JOIN..ON versus UNION.

Comment: @RickJames i just want to merge the two tables which may have some columns with same name and different in no of columns. Ie the result will be  another table.

Comment: So, the total number of ROWs will be the sum of the number of rows in the existing tables?  Sorry to keep asking question, but your specification is still imprecise.

Comment: @RickJames yes. the total no of columns will be the merged sum of two tables. For ex. if TB1A have 5 col,TB2A have 8 columns but 3 columns are common i  the two table table so the total no of column in the resultant table will be.`10( 5(from TB1A)+5(from TB2A))`. I thin you got my idea.

Comment: Note - You;ve already stated the total # of columns would be 8 (the five columns in `TB1A` all existing in `TB2A` - please correct question if that's wrong). **We're asking about the # of *rows***. ...

Comment: If there are *m* rows in `TB1A`, and *n* rows in `TB2A` then we either: Insert all rows from `TB1A`, and separately insert all rows from `TB2A` (*m + n* rows); join every rows in `TB1A` to every row in `TB2A` (_m * n_ rows); insert all rows from `TB2A`, then all rows from `TB1A` that don't match an existing row in the overlapping columns; or (if all columns in `TB1A` don't overlap`TB2A`'s columns), we `FULL JOIN` rows in `TB1A` and `TB2A`, so rows only in `TB1A` go in as is, rows only in `TB2A` go in as is, and the combined columns from the matching rows go in as a single row.

Answer (score 2):

What you've entered is equivalent to:

```
CREATE TABLE TB3A AS (

SELECT a.AgreementID, a.Column2, a.Column3, a.Column4,
       a.Column5, b.AgreementID, b.Column2, b.Column3,
       b.Column4, b.Column5, b.Column6, b.Column7, b.Column8
  FROM TB1A a JOIN TB2A b
);
```

You'd have 13 columns, with only 8 distinct names. This is a problem.

What you probably want to do is this:

```
CREATE TABLE TB3A AS (

SELECT AgreementID, Column2, Column3, Column4,
       Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8
  FROM TB2A
);

INSERT INTO TB3A (AgreementID, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
SELECT * FROM TB1A;
```

`TB3A` will now have *m* + *n* rows, where *m* is the number of rows in `TB1A`, and *n* is the number of rows in `TB2A`.

If some rows in `TB1A` and `TB2A` are duplicates, this will not remove those. You can change the `INSERT ... SELECT` statement to filter out rows from `TB1A` that match rows already in `TB3A` (thus, originally from `TB2A`) with matching values in whatever columns you need. For instance, to not bring in rows from `TB1A` that have the same `AgreementId` as rows already in `TB3A`, the `INSERT` would be:

```
INSERT INTO TB3A (AgreementID, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5)
SELECT * FROM TB1A 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TB3A
                    WHERE TB1A.AgreementID = TB3A.AgreementId
                  )
;
```

---

Additional note on the original statement: `JOIN` is generally assumed to be an `INNER JOIN` - one that matches rows form the two tables based on one or more criteria. For example, `TB1A JOIN TB2A ON TB1A.AgreementId = TB2A.AgreementId` would return the rows from `TB1A` and `TB2A` the had the same `AgreementID`. Rows in `TB1A` with an `AgreementID` *not* found in `TB2A` would not be returned, and rows in `TB2A` with an `AgreementID` *not* found in `TB1A` would not be returned.

If there were three rows in `TB1A` with the same `AgreementId`, and 2 rows in `TB2A` with that same ID, those rows would generate 6 rows in the result set:

```
TB1A      TB2A
  x         m
  y         n
  z

Result set:
    x,m
    x,n
    y,m
    y,n
    z,m
    z,n
```

In some SQL dialects (MySQL included), if there is no `JOIN` criteria specified, then the `INNER JOIN` becomes what's called a `CROSS JOIN`. Here, since there's nothing to indicate which rows should not be joined together, *all* rows are joined together. If you have *m* rows in `TB1A`, and *n* rows in `TB2A`, you don't get *m+n* rows - you get ***m*n*** rows. That's what would have happened, if your original statement had run.

Comment: I guess that the OP wants something else and not a join. Perhaps a `UNION`, not sure.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  please see the comments below thw questions. This will clear you. Thnaks

Comment: @PranavMS it's still not clear if you want a `UNION` or some kind of `JOIN`. It would be better if you **edited** your question and added sample data and wanted result.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by providing alias or `db.table` as below.

```
CREATE TABLE TB3A AS (
  SELECT A.coli, A.col2, A.col3, A.col4, A.col5    
  FROM DB1.TB1A A    
  JOIN  DB2.TB2A B)
```